# Finding whether number 4 is prime or not?

Tags: java

Here is my program, inside `for` loop `Math.sqrt(n)` - I think here is error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNoCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");

        int n = s.nextInt();

        if (isPrime(n)) {
            System.out.println(n + " is a prime number");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n + " is not a prime number");
        }

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 4 is not a prime, problem solved. :)

Comment: You should just do a hard check for `n%2==0` before your loop.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: @gonzo would be better to just start at 3 and increment by 2

Comment: Please include the error you are getting. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed the code formatting for you, but please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Maxqueue oh don't get me started on _better_ there is a ton of stuff you can do. I just thought that would be the simplest solution in this context. Personally I start at 6, incrementing by 6 checking one above and one below so first iteration I would check 5 and 7...

Comment: Btw, `i < Math.sqrt(n)` with `i = 2` and `n = 4` would never let the loop run since `2 < sqrt(4)` is false.

Comment: Square root of 4 is 2 ? 2 < 2 is false ? So your code with 4 never enter the loop.

Comment: In order to avoid bringing floating-point into the problem, it would be best to use the condition `i * i < n` in place of `i < Math.sqrt(n)`.  Probably a bit faster, too.  This ignores the question of whether that's the condition you actually ought to be testing, however.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Are you sure it will be faster ? My guess is that `i * i` is not constant and needs to be computed at each iteration, while `Math.sqrt(n)` can be JITed since `n` does not change.

Comment: @AlexisC, I am not *positive* that `i * i` would be faster under all circumstances, but generally speaking, JIT cannot lift a method invocation out of a loop, even though the arguments are always the same, because the method could have side effects that then would not occur.  Certainly a *single* evaluation of `i * i` should be expected to be far faster than a single invocation of `Math.sqrt(n)`.

Comment: just the same error: replace i * i < n    by    i * i <= n

Comment: guys according for loop check the condition then only increment takes place right?according to this i=2;i<Math.sqrt(n);what does it mean?sqrt(4) it root cases 4=root(2)*root(2) ,sorry I am not good math ..so finally I got output 4 is prime number.

Answer (score 3):

the algorithm is: 
To check if n is a prime number, you have to try to divide it by all the numbers, from 2 (1 is useless), to sqrt(n), included.

You don't have to check after sqrt(n), because, if n can be divided by X,
greater than sqrt(n), it also can be divided by Y (n/X), lesser than sqrt(n), or by Z, lesser than Y, if Y is not prime.

The error in you code is that you stop just before sqrt(n).

With your code 4, 9, 25, ... are seen as prime, and every  prime ^2 also.

just Replace that:  <= instead of <

```
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
```

Comment: "What" is nice, somewhat. ***Why*** is even better.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? -  T.J Crowder How it Works this For Loop?

Comment: You could improve this by hard-checking if `n` is even before the loop, then start the loop at 3, and do `i += 2`

Comment: yes, but if you really want to improve a lot, you must use mathematical methods, much more difficult to understand.

Comment: then ?What I did dude guillaume girod-vitouchkina just make it simple?